# ClickOnce deployment: Is it possible to register application for Active Directory Federation Service?

Tags: wpf, installation, clickonce, adfs, ws-federation

Is it possible to execute Windows PowerShell command to register an application to ADFS using ClickOnce deployment?

I am working on a WPF rich client application. The application using REST API to authenticate and get data. The authentication will be performed by Active Directory Federation Services. As to authenticated and to get token, I have to register the client application with ADFS, can I execute PowerShell command through clickOnce setup to register application to ADFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register the client in ADFS using powershell, but that is something that is done only once in the ADFS server itself. So I don't see the benefit of including that registration through clickOnce. This document describes your scenario (WPF client + OAuth + ADFS), you can find more information there: [Developing Modern Applications using OAuth and Active Directory Federation Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn633593.aspx)